# Java update program configuration

Tags: java, multithreading, configuration, volatile

I have a multithreaded program that loads its configuration on startup. The configuration is then handed down to the threads via their constructors.

But now I want to load one new config instance regularly, and pass it to the threads.

One idea would be to make the reference in the thread class to the config file volatile. Then, when an updated config instance is available, call a update `update(Config c)` method.

Is this the way to go? I will have terrible performance because every time the thread needs some setting it has to do all that volatile checking stuff.

Some better suggestions? Best practice? Maybe don't make it volatile and hope that the processor fetches that new object from main memory from time to time?

Comment: How crucial to have your configuration updated? Can you refresh it once in 5 seconds? In this case volatile won't impact performance significantly

Comment: It can even be 1 min before every thread knowns the new settings. But I don'T want to see half read config objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, are you sure that will have terrible performance?

If volatile used mostly for reading it's performance is not that bad. I'd recommend to try volatile first and measure performance degradation and **only if it's significant then do any rework**.

If you are really worrying about rapid volatile reads - then in you run method in thread you could have check for timeout - if 60 seconds passed since last config read - then reread it. Logic will reversed from `update(Config c)`, to

```
if(moreThan60SecondsPassed)
{
localConfig = configconfigHolder.getConfig();
}
```

Also, if you'll be using non volatile - you won't get half read config. The danger is that you could have some threads not see updated value forever (no happens-before relationship).

Bw, did you consider recreating threads on config update? In this case you still could pass config through constructor. It depends on how often you want to update configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You could encapsulate all of your configuration values in a single immutable object, and when the configuration changes create a new instance of the object, and pass it to the threads, through listeners or explicit calling. The object has no `volatile` fields, only the object itself could be written in a `volatile` variable (or an `AtomicReference`).

The direct `volatile` approach with no other synchronization mechanisms is dangerous: you could read a halfway-rewritten configuration.

In any case, the performance impact on your application is likely to be negligible. Think about optimization later, if you find this is really a bottleneck.

Comment: Is it possible to read half-finished configs if one thread loads the config completly (multiple ojects in hierarchical order in this config object). And then the that same config-loader thread passes this new config to all other threads? I don't quite understand which references have to be volatile? Let's talk about Config-Loader-Thread, Worker-Thread and Config-Object (containing Config-Sub-Objects)

Comment: Config-Object does not need any volatile variable. Inside Worker-Thread you could declare a `AtomicReference<ConfigObject> config` field. In Config-Loader-Thread you can create a new instance of Config-Object, and store it inside the `config` variable of each Worker-Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use observer pattern to notify the threads of new config via listeners.

There is no way you can avoid volatile checking stuff. Maybe is expensive(do some performance tests) but your program will run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/):

> A common issue with file-based configurations is to handle the reloading of the data file when it changes. This is especially important if you have long running applications and do not want to restart them when a configuration file was updated. Commons Configuration has the concept of so called reloading strategies that can be associated with a file-based configuration. Such a strategy monitors a configuration file and is able to detect changes. A default reloading strategy is FileChangedReloadingStrategy. It can be set on a file-based configuration as follows.
>
> `ManagedReloadingStrategy` is an alternative to automatic reloading. It allows to hot-reload properties on a running application but only when requested by admin. The refresh() method will force a reload of the configuration source.